# How to make .img with used space only using dd

Tags: dd

So I installed Ubuntu on a 32GB SD card, and made all the settings and adjustments that I need.

Now I want to start to burn this image into a device that has only 8GB memory in its `eMMC`.

The used space on the SD card is just 1.4GB and I want to make an image that is 8GB using `dd`. I tried different things, but it didn't work.

````
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            464M     0  464M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M  1.3M   99M   2% /run
overlay          29G  1.4G   28G   5% /
tmpfs           500M     0  500M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           500M     0  500M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0```

:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29.74 GiB, 31914983424 bytes, 62333952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc9c537b6

Device         Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        49152   131071    81920   40M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/mmcblk0p2       131072  2361343  2230272  1.1G 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3      2361344 62333951 59972608 28.6G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 7.29 GiB, 7818182656 bytes, 15269888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc9c537b6

Device         Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1        49152   131071    81920   40M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/mmcblk1p2       131072  2361343  2230272  1.1G 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk1p3      2361344 62333951 59972608 28.6G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mmcblk1boot1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mmcblk1boot0: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
````

`eMMC` is `/dev/mmcblk1`.

Comment: You should have started with a smaller partition on the 32 GB card. If you know that you require less space use a smaller partition, e.g. 5 GB, then it should fit on the target device, too.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/a/610825/1001901). Maybe you don't need to be told, but... always be careful with `dd` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. `dd` reads raw disk blocks, and "free/used space" is a filesystem concept. `dd` has no way of identifying "free/used space".

Comment: Thanks, but then what will be the option for me? Or i should start over on a 8GB SD card?

Answer (score 0):

So i solved this problem using a Linux VM on my Mac. I installed gparted and from there it was really easy. First you must unmount the SD Card, then resize it to the size you want and you are done. Really easy.